# What's the difference between 2to3-2.7 and 2to3-3.1?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, ubuntu-12.04, python-2to3

My Ubuntu 12.04 stock python install has 2 programs for converting code to Python 3.x: `2to3-2.7` and `2to3-3.1`. What's the difference?

Comment: I think one runs using Python 2.7 and the other runs using 3.1

Comment: `(2to3 - 2.7) - (2to3 - 3.1)` is `-0.4` .... HTH :-)

Comment: Um... One converts from `v2` to `v3-2.7` and the other converts from `v2` to `v3-3.1`?

Comment: One is version 2.7 and the other is newer than that?  Why not download the source and check the release notes?

Comment: As an aside: Ubuntu 12.04 should have `2to3-3.2`, not 3.1.

Comment: seems my update mirror hasn't put python 3.2 up yet. Waiting waiting waiting!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They are both 2to3, but one is part of your Python 2.7 installation, and the other is part of your Python 3.1 installation.

If you look at the bin directory in a Python X.Y installation, each foo executable will also be named foo-X.Y, so that you can run a specific version by name.